# Castle Windsor: ResolveAll does not return services with constructor parameters

Tags: service, constructor, castle-windsor

I have an interface and two classes that implements it. One of them has a parameter in its constructor. I have registered both of them as services in my app.config. Unfortunately I'm not able to resolve both of them in my code: the class with constructor is not returned.

E.g.:

```
interface ITest
{
}

class Test : ITest
{
    private string a;

    public Test(string a)        
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class Test2 : ITest
{
}
```

Here is my configuration:

```
<castle>
    <components>
        <component id="Test" type="XYZ.Test, XYZ" service="XYZ.ITest, XYZ"/>                
        <component id="Test2" type="XYZ.Test2, XYZ" service="XYZ.ITest, XYZ"/>
    </components>
</castle>
```

And here is how I try to get my services in code:

```
ITest[] resolveAll = container.ResolveAll<ITest>(new {a ="aText" });
```

The array "resolveAll" only contains 'Test2' but no trace of 'Test'. How can I do to get these two classes ?

I note that if I resolve with id "Test":

```
object resolve = container.Resolve("Test", new { sessionId = "sessionId" });
```

I obtain my 'Test' class.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was on an old version of Castle Windsor. On last version (3.1), this works.